# Single term for "non-fatal casualty"

Tags: single-word-requests, military

from my Marine Corps days, I recall that "casualty" implies the basic idea of removing a Marine from being an active combatant. This can occur through severe injuries, death, capture, going UA, etc.

The term casualty, then, can apply to deaths and all those other things, lumped into the phrase "non-fatal casualty." Is there a single word that captures that same meaning? I feel that there is, but can't remember! Or, I could simply be wrongly remembering that there was a single word... in which case, curses on getting old.

Comment: It's a multi-word, but **taken out of commission** at least includes casualties without implying death.

Comment: Domain-specific military terminology is probably Off Topic, but newspapers and other sources of "normal" English routinely refer to the two types of casualities (killed and wounded) as *[the] **dead*** and *[the] **injured***.

Comment: Not making it an answer because you said the word in the question, but the word is just "injured"

Comment: Not specific to military context but there is [*nonfatality*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonfatality). It is used in military context also. See: [Google books](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22non-fatal+casualty%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VahTVcetF46tyASCkIAg#q=%22non-fatalities%22+military&tbm=bks)

Comment: There is also *disabled* or *incapacitated*. I see various analogs in sports, the favorite I saw was a term called *PUP* (physically unable to perform).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Casualty" is broader than killed and injured -- it also includes anyone who was captured or deserted.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the military distinction does make this a slightly different beast. In civilian usage, all injuries (regardless of severity) and deaths are casualties. In military usage, all deaths are casualties, but not all injuries; only those injuries that remove a combatant from active service are classified as casualties. @jxh, I think "incapacitated" captures what I was going for, if you'd like to generate an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***incapacitated*** can be used to describe a soldier that is no longer able to fulfill their duties.

> : to make (someone or something) unable to work, move, or function in the usual way
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incapacitate)</sub>

It seems to show up in military material as a term similar to ***disability*** for civilians. For example:

> DA PAM 135-381 (Incapacitation of Reserve Component Soldiers Processing Procedures) defines ***Incapacitation*** (INCAP) as a physical disability due to injury, illness, or disease that prevents the performance of military duties, or which prevents the Soldier from returning to the civilian occupation in which the Soldier was employed at the time of the injury, illness, or disease.
>   <sub>[Army National Guard](https://g1arng.army.pentagon.mil/processes/incappayprocess/Pages/default.aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

WIA (Wounded in action) or Medical casualty is as far as I get.

Comment: These miss some casualties: deserters and POWs are also casualties.